# Using flask-sqlalchemy, how to specify user-defined data type in database table column

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a rest api service in python that talks to a Postgres database. I am using flake-sqlalchemy to do so. In the table, one of the columns is defined as:

`my_column my_type not null`

And my_type is defined:

`create type my_type as emum ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`

How do I represent this in flask-sqlalchemy? Thanks you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

your app.py definition goes like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://test:test@localhost/test?charset=utf8mb4' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db, compare_type=True)

class CustEnum(TypeDecorator):
    impl = CHAR(4)
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        valid_values = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
        if value not in valid_values:
            raise TypeError(f"mismatch {value} not in {valid_values} ")
            
        return value

class Blobby(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_col = db.Column(CustEnum())
```

where the `process_bind_param` method is basically the setter method and `process_result_value` is the getter method.

refer to doc for more on it
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator

I also like to add a test function to the file with the cli decorator to check it works.

```
@app.cli.command("testit")
def testit():
    newblob = Blobby(type_col = 'val2')
    db.session.add( newblob )
    db.session.commit()
    
    for row in db.session.execute('select * from blobby'):
        print(row)
    
    input('press enter to continue to failure test')
    # value not allowed should fail
    newblob = Blobby(type_col = 'fail')
    db.session.add( newblob )
    db.session.commit()
```

When you apply the migration (i.e running `flask db init`, `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade`), you get an error that name app.CustEnum cant be found.

```
sa.Column('type_col', app.CustEnum(length=4), nullable=True),
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Searching for a fix for that I found the author of the library says you need to update the migration script itself which is kinda backwards IMO.

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/282#issuecomment-518989508

so just edit `migrations/versions/98f29efa609f_.py` or whatever your version is. and add `import app` or whatever your flask script's namespace is.

last thing is to run the test with `flask testit` to run the testit() function to give you one success and one failure.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) mismatch fail not in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
[SQL: INSERT INTO blobby (type_col) VALUES (%(type_col)s)]
[parameters: [{'type_col': 'fail'}]]
```